# Android - Facebook -- Use native method to share a post under the OFFLINE, app crash

Tags: android, facebook

## 1.Condition

Facebook-SDK-4.8.1

## 2.Description

When I use the native share-post method to share the Facebook-post under the offline, the app CRASH, and output some strange logs.

Because there is no official Resource to explain, so my solution process is below

1. Submission? -- **(NO)**

I apply the new submission - "publish_actions", then share offline, app crash, the log is same as the above.

2. Try the catch the Exception Error? -- **(NO)**

I have added the catcher, but I cannot catch it.

My

## 3.Error Log

```
12-04 09:49:08.765 10386-10112/? W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
                                                                      com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:08.770 10386-10062/? W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
                                                                      com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:08.880 10386-10138/? W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue: Exception during service
                                                                      com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.110 3139-3139/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package com.dianping.v1 by user request.
12-04 09:49:09.120 3139-3139/? E/NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package com.dianping.v1 by user request.
12-04 09:49:09.445 10386-10014/? E/fb4a(:<default>):ACRA: Handling exception for soft error
                                                          com.facebook.common.errorreporting.SoftErrorException: sessionId: 1c92c8ba-c143-496d-bdca-ce53d86f020d
                                                              at com.facebook.common.errorreporting.FbErrorReporterImpl.a(μs:153)
                                                              at com.facebook.composer.feedattachment.ShareComposerAttachmentController.a(ON_SUGGESTIONS:274)
                                                              at com.facebook.composer.feedattachment.ComposerFeedAttachmentFragment$2.a(OUTGOING_REQUEST:137)
                                                              at com.facebook.common.futures.AbstractDisposableFutureCallback.onFailure(tn:48)
                                                              at com.facebook.ui.futures.TasksManager$CallbackWithCleanup.onFailure(validate_payment_card_bin:313)
                                                              at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5.run(zero_rating2/clearable/:1222)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                              at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(video_inline_android_shutoff:77)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                           Caused by: com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                              at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                              at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                              at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                              at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                              at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.530 10386-10153/? W/fb4a(:<default>):CacheReadRunner: Exception during graphql executor query
                                                                     com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.535 10386-10153/? E/fb4a(:<default>):SimpleExecutor: Exception in background task
                                                                    com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.555 10386-10155/? W/fb4a(:<default>):CacheReadRunner: Exception during graphql executor query
                                                                     com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.560 10386-10155/? E/fb4a(:<default>):SimpleExecutor: Exception in background task
                                                                    com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException: getaddrinfo failure: No address associated with hostname
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.handleError(min_sponsored_gap:244)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.LigerHttpResponseHandler.onError(min_sponsored_gap:209)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.JniHandler.onError(onStop():109)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.EventBase.loopForever(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPThread.run(offers_claim:32)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-04 09:49:09.570 10386-10386/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a4c50)
12-04 09:49:09.580 10386-10386/? E/AppStateLoggerExceptionHandler: Handing uncaught exception
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.facebook.proxygen.HttpNetworkException)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
                                                                       at com.facebook.fbservice.service.OperationResult.writeToParcel(should_show_nub:474)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
                                                                       at com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException.writeToParcel(data_cleanup:66)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7029)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2285)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4269)
                                                                       at com.facebook.base.activity.FbFragmentActivity.finish(sticker:335)
                                                                       at com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerFragment.a(PAGE_TIPS:2072)
                                                                       at com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerFragment$58.a(PAGE_TIPS:2091)
                                                                       at com.facebook.common.futures.AbstractDisposableFutureCallback.onFailure(tn:48)
                                                                       at com.facebook.ui.futures.TasksManager$CallbackWithCleanup.onFailure(validate_payment_card_bin:313)
                                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5.run(zero_rating2/clearable/:1222)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                       at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(video_inline_android_shutoff:77)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.facebook.proxygen.HTTPRequestError
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1366)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:981)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1076)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                                       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1311)
                                                                       at com.facebook.fbservice.service.OperationResult.writeToParcel(should_show_nub:474) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.fbservice.service.ServiceException.writeToParcel(data_cleanup:66) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636) 
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7029) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2285) 
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4269) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.base.activity.FbFragmentActivity.finish(sticker:335) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerFragment.a(PAGE_TIPS:2072) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.composer.activity.ComposerFragment$58.a(PAGE_TIPS:2091) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.common.futures.AbstractDisposableFutureCallback.onFailure(tn:48) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.ui.futures.TasksManager$CallbackWithCleanup.onFailure(validate_payment_card_bin:313) 
                                                                       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5.run(zero_rating2/clearable/:1222) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                                       at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(video_inline_android_shutoff:77) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the *native share-post*? can you provide some code? what do you mean by *under the offline*? In all cases, I would recommend you try sharing using one of the bundled sample projects using the latest SDK and see if that helps then check what's the difference between your app and the bundled example.

Comment: Thanks @ifaour. Your suggestion is good.
What i mean is that I want to share some stories to Facebook when the mobile phone not connected to the Internet.
Fortunately, I have found the solution to implement my requirement.
My solution is set the value of the "Caption" field.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution is set the value of the "Caption" field.**